# HELP! MySQL Join Many to Many + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, join, many-to-many

And how to write MySQL Join and PHP?
Or you can make another? ...

Examples:

```
Table 1:
movie_id | movie_title
1______  | title_movie_1
2______  | title_movie_2
3______  | title_movie_3
```

```
Table 2:
genre_id | genre_title
1______  | title_genre_1
2______  | title_genre_2
3______  | title_genre_3
```

```
Table 3:
id | movie_id | genre_1
1_ | __1____ | _1
1_ | __1____ | _2
1_ | __2____ | _1
1_ | __2____ | _3
1_ | __3____ | _1
1_ | __3____ | _3
1_ | __3____ | _2
```

Results PHP:

```
Movie: title_movie_1
Genre: 
_a href="genre/1 (id_genre)">title_genre_1 _/a>, 
_a href="genre/2">title_genre_2 _/a>

Movie: title_movie_2
Genre: 
_a href="genre/1">title_genre_1 _/a>,
_a href="genre/3">title_genre_3 _/a>

Movie: title_movie_3
Genre: 
_a href="genre/1">title_genre_1 _/a>
_a href="genre/2">title_genre_2 _/a>
_a href="genre/3">title_genre_3 _/a>
```

I can not find do ...
**Help, please! I'm waiting!**

Sincerely, Areku

Comment: Stackoverflow is very active community, so you don't have to scream to get answer. Be polite, write short rich questions and you will have lot of good answers.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
  table1.movie_title AS movie_title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(table2.genre_title) AS genre_titles
FROM
  table3
INNER JOIN
  table1
  ON table1.movie_id = table3.movie_id
INNER JOIN
  table2
  ON table2.genre_id = table3.genre_id
```

Results:

```
title_movie_1 | title_genre_1,title_genre_2
title_movie_2 | title_genre_1,title_genre_3
title_movie_3 | title_genre_1,title_genre_2,title_genre_3
```

Php code :

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("server", "user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT ... FROM ...") 
or die(mysql_error());  

// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
  echo "Movie: " + $row['movie_title'];
  echo "Genre: " + $row['genres_title'];
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.movie_title, t2.genre_title
FROM table_1 t1, table_2 t2, table_3 t3
WHERE t1.movie_id = t3.movie_id
AND t2.genre_id = t3.genre_id;
```